# Angular 8 ngForm not performing action

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to use ngForm by following an online tutorial for building the full-stack application but save button isn't triggered, I am totally new to angular 8 I had followed each step kidly help me to get rid of this thanks in advance

**My form code adduer.component.html**

```
<h1>Add User</h1>
<form #recievedUser="ngForm">

  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="user name" [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name">

  <label for="type">Type</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="type" placeholder="type name" [(ngModel)]="user.type" name="name">

  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password">

  <br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="addUser()">Save</button>
</form>
```

**My adduser.Component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../../model/User';
import { HttpClientService } from '../../../service/http-client.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-adduser',
  templateUrl: './adduser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adduser.component.css']
})
export class AdduserComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  user: User

  @Output()
  userAddedEvent = new EventEmitter();

  newUser: User;
  message: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);

  }

  addUser() {
    this.httpClientService.addUser(this.newUser).subscribe(
      (user) => {
        this.userAddedEvent.emit();
        this.router.navigate(['admin', 'users']);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './admin/users/users.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AdduserComponent } from './admin/users/adduser/adduser.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    AdduserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am following [this link](https://www.javainuse.com/fullstack/ecommerce/user2)  to build an application

Answer (score 0):

I don't see declared the ngSubmit Output of the directive ngForm. Try to put it in your form HTML tag.

```
<form #recievedUser="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addUser()">
```

Then remove the click button event

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
```

Try it.

Comment: Try to put the button type to "submit"

Answer (score 0):

1. `user` is an input, and you assign `this.newUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);` it to `this.newUser` in `ngOnInit`. It means the `this.newUser` get the original input value of `user` and won't get the new value when you use it in `addUser()` (you can check more about `ngOnInit`).
2. To get value from ngForm, you can pass the form like `(click)="addUser(recievedUser)"` then access its values by `recievedUser.controls.[nameOfControl].[value]` (ex: `recievedUser.controls.name.value`). You can use `console.log(recievedUser.controls.name)` to see it.

To fix your problem, you can:

1. Move `this.newUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);` into `addUser()` so it can get the latest value

   `addUser() {`

   ```
    this.newUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);

    this.httpClientService.addUser(this.newUser).subscribe(

    (user) => {

      this.userAddedEvent.emit();

      this.router.navigate(['admin', 'users']);

    });
   ```

   `}`

Or 2. Keep `this.newUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);` in `ngOnInit` and change the binding from `user` to `newUser` (`[(ngModel)]="newUser.name"`).